# Firebase dependencies create errors on runtime

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies

```
Error: Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcar`.
```

Continuously getting same issues whatever I am trying. Nothing work.

```
Java Compiler:
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/play-services-gass-11.0.4.aar/c9497d6850772046db2c4c9a12ec798a/jars/classes.jar

Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcar`.
```

build.gradle(app):-

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'

implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}

implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1'
```

build.gradle(project):-

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
}
```

If anyone know where I am going wrong, please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Try remove the `exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'` from at least one of firebase imports in gradle

Comment: tried..not working :(

Comment: `com.firebase:firebase-client-android` is the old legacy FIrebase.  You should consider [upgrading](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#update_your_database_code) to use `firebase-database`.

Comment: Hello, Were you able to fix the issue? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Just this should work:

```
dependencies {
 // ...
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
}
```

Comment: maybe an older version works did you try ```implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'```

Answer (score 0):

For the people who got this issue when trying to use Firebase and AdMob together, check the below link in Ionic Forum.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-firebase-and-admob-free-together/117650/2?u=vigamage

Issue is caused by the different play services versions used by the plugins.
For example, firebase plugin always use the latest. But AdMob free plugin uses a specific version. (11.0.4)

To fix it, instruct the AdMob plugin to use the latest version by doing below in admob sdk plugin.xml.

```
<platform name="android">
        <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+" />
        <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+" />
</platform>
```

Note that, After doing this, you might have to re-import some classes in Android Studio since the packages might be different in the latest version.